# How to create sphere based pie chart with three.js?

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to create similar mesh in three.js?
Basically this is 3D pie chart clipped by half-sphere. 
The only idea I have is to use [clipping planes](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clip#webgl_clipping_intersection). Is there more simple approach?

[image: preview]

Comment: Perhaps a combination of this: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping#webgl_clipping_intersection and this: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping#webgl_clipping_stencil ? Stack Overflow it's really a place for brainstorming. If you aren't experiencing a specific, answerable problem, then you might find better responses on the three.js forum. https://discourse.threejs.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on exactly what you want but the [SphereBufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/SphereBufferGeometry) has parameters to create less than the entire sphere. The 4th and 5th parameters set the start and length around the width. The 6th and 7th set the start and length around the height

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 2, 1.5);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
  
  const cameraStick = new THREE.Object3D();
  scene.add(cameraStick);
  cameraStick.add(camera);

  function addLight(...pos) {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(...pos);
    scene.add(light);
  }
  addLight(-1, 2, 4);
  addLight( 1, 2, -4);
  
  const amounts = [
    123,
    47,
  ];
  const total = amounts.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  amounts.reduce((amountSoFar, amount, ndx) => {
    const geo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(
       1, // radius
       32, // width segments
       16, // height segments
       amountSoFar / total * Math.PI * 2,  // phiStart
       amount / total * Math.PI * 2,  // phiLength
       0, // thetaStart
       Math.PI / 2, // thetaLength
    );
    const mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    mat.color.setHSL(amountSoFar / total, 1, 0.5);
    scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat));
    return amountSoFar + amount;
  }, 0);
  
  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    
    cameraStick.rotation.y = time;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

If you want to seal the bottom and the sides you have several options.

1. Write your own sphere generation code. Just copy [the source from three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/geometries/SphereGeometry.js) and add [code to add the faces to seal the sides](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-geometry.html)
2. Use [`CircleBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CircleBufferGeometry) that has similar parameters to make the sides and ends. It's up to you if you want to [merge those into a single geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries).

Note that trying to draw a chart like that with transparency will [have issues](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-transparency.html).

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 2, 1.5);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
  
  const cameraStick = new THREE.Object3D();
  scene.add(cameraStick);
  cameraStick.add(camera);

  function addLight(...pos) {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(...pos);
    scene.add(light);
  }
  addLight(-1, 2, 4);
  addLight( 1, 2, -4);
  
  const amounts = [
    120,
    35,
  ];
  const total = amounts.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  amounts.reduce((amountSoFar, amount, ndx) => {
    const arc = amount / total * Math.PI * 2;
    
    const base = new THREE.Object3D();
    scene.add(base);
    base.rotation.y = (amountSoFar / total) * Math.PI * 2 + arc / 2;
    
    const offset = new THREE.Object3D();
    offset.position.x = -0.05;
    base.add(offset);    

    const geo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(
       1, // radius
       32, // width segments
       16, // height segments
       -arc / 2,  // phiStart;
       arc,  // phiLength,
       0, // thetaStart
       Math.PI / 2, // thetaLength
    );
    const mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    mat.color.setHSL(amountSoFar / total, 1, 0.5);
    const wedge = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    offset.add(wedge);
    
    const end = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(
       1, // radius
       16, // segments
       Math.PI / 2, // thetaStart
       Math.PI / 2, // thetaLength
    );
    
    const endMesh = new THREE.Mesh(end, mat);
    endMesh.rotation.y = arc / 2;
    offset.add(endMesh);

    const end2 = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(
       1, // radius
       16, // segments
       0, // thetaStart
       Math.PI / 2, // thetaLength
    );

    const endMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(end2, mat);
    endMesh2.rotation.y = Math.PI - arc / 2;
    offset.add(endMesh2);

    const bottom = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(
       1, // radius
       32, // segments
       Math.PI + -arc / 2, // thetaStart
       arc, // thetaLength
    );

    const bottomMesh = new THREE.Mesh(bottom, mat);
    bottomMesh.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    offset.add(bottomMesh);

    return amountSoFar + amount;
  }, 0);
  
  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    
    cameraStick.rotation.y = time;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for such  detailed answer, @gman! Special thank for pointing to transparency issues!